# Using a "for statement" to simplify bash statement with multiple repeats

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm subsetting a filename via `grep` and then concatenating the resulting files with `cat`. However, I'm still a bit confused as to how I should use the for statement, e.g. `for ((i=1;i<23;i+=1));`

Given my file `file1.txt`, I would like to grep `sample1` as follows:

```
grep -w '^sample1' file1.txt > sample1_file.txt
grep -w '^sample2' file2.txt > sample2_file.txt
grep -w '^sample3' file3.txt > sample3_file.txt
....
grep -w '^sample22' file22.txt > sample22_file.txt
```

And then concatenate these:

```
cat  sample1_file.txt  sample2_file.txt  sample3_file.txt ...  sample22_file.txt > final_output.txt
```

Comment: I'd try to create a string `FOO="^sample1|^sample2|..."` and then `grep -e ""$FOO"" > final_output.txt`.  Not tested, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
for i in {1..22}
do
    grep -w "^sample$i" "file$i.txt"
done >final_output.txt
```

#### Notes:

1. `{1..22}` runs through all the integers from 1 to 22.  For people not familiar with C, it is probably more intuitive (but less flexible) than `((i=1;i<23;i+=1))`
2. It is important that the expression `^sample$i` be inside double-quotes rather than single-quotes so that the shell will expand `$i`.
3. If all you want is `final_output.txt`, there is no need to create the intermediate files.
4. Notice that it is efficient to place the redirection to  `final_output.txt` after the `done` statement: in this way, the shell needs to open and close this file only once.

Comment: Now I realize my mistake, please edit your answer so I could remove my downvote, sorry for the noise and thanks.

Comment: @BLayer No I can not, it is locked after some time (maybe I need more reputation to be able to do so).

Comment: @isaac Okay. Maybe the time until lockout is shorter than I thought.

Comment: `done >final_output.txt` These will cat in the "right order"?

Comment: @EB2127 Yes, they `cat` in the same order that the `grep` commands are run.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed I have an extra '^sampleA' and '^sampleB'.  I'll add these commands after done. Thanks!

Comment: I did not know any piping could be placed after `done`

Comment: @TannerBabcock Yes and it is very useful.  A redirection placed after `done` captures all output from the loop.  Separately, if you don't have a loop but you still want to capture output from multiple commands, you can use grouping with curly braces and place the redirection after the closing curly brace: `{ cmd1; cmd2; ...; } >outputfile`.

Answer (score 2):

You [reference parameters and variables with the dollar sign](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), so the loop counter `i` can be used as `$i` within the loop (within double quotes, not single quotes). Then you just need the [`do` and `done` keywords to start and end the loopy part](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Loops_.28while.2C_until_and_for.29).

So, the straightforward conversion:

```
> final_output.txt
for (( i = 1 ; i < 23 ; i += 1)); do
    grep -w "^sample$i" "file$i.txt" > "sample${i}_file.txt"
    cat "sample${i}_file.txt" >> final_output.txt
done
```

Using the quotes around `"file${i}.txt"` is not strictly necessary as long as `i` only contains a number, but it's a good habit to quote any variable references, for lots of reasons.

Note that in the case of `sample${i}_file.txt` we need the braces in `${i}`, since the underscore is valid in a variable name, and writing `$i_file.txt` would refer to the variable `i_file`.

The initial `> final_output.txt` is to clear the file at first, since we append to it within the loop. Of course, you can just skip creating the `sample1_file.txt` files if you don't need them, and just `grep ... >> final_output.txt`.

Alternatively, you could use [*brace expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) to generate a list of the numbers, instead of counting manually with the  `for (( ... ))` loop, i.e. `for i in {1..22}; do ... done`.

Or, in standard POSIX shell:

```
i=1
while [ "$i" -lt 23 ] ; do
    grep ...
    i=$((i + 1))
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
#/bin/bash
:>final_output.txt
for i in {1..22}; do
    a=file"$i".txt
    b=sample"$i"_file.txt

    grep -w '^sample'"$i" "$a" > "$b"
    cat "$b" >> final_output.txt
done
```

The line `:>final_output` clears the file to 0 bytes.
The "Brace expansion" `{1..22}` expands to the list of numbers 1 2 3 … 22.
The line `for i in {1..22}; do` loops over all numbers 1 … 22.
The "Append" (`>>`) is required as we want to store all outputs to the file.

Comment: why do the round-trip around the positional parameters?

Comment: @ilkkachu I find it more expressive, but fine, removed.